# First CLIPS code doesnt work

Tags: system, clips, expert-system

I wrote my first CLIPS code for a school project but I am not familiar with CLIPS (I use C# and python as main languages).

This is my code and the errors I am gettin:

```
(defrule determine-closing-date
    (not (day-to-close ?))
    (billing-size ?)
    (unpaid-invoices-number ?)
    =>
    (if 
        (or 
            (< billing-size 1000000)
            (< unpaid-invoices-number 1000000)
        )
        then (assert (day-to-close MtTh))
        else (assert (day-to-close friday))
    )

(defrule determine-billing-size ""
    (not (billing-size ?))
    (not (day-to-close ?))
    =>
    (printout t "¿Cuál es el tamaño de la facturacion?")
    (assert (billing-size ?size (read))))

(defrule determine-unpaid-invoices-number ""
    (not (unpaid-invoices-number ?))
    (not (day-to-close ?))
    =>
    (printout t "¿Cuál es la cantidad de facturas no pagadas")
    (assert (unpaid-invoices-number ?size (read))))

(defrule determine-friday-load ""
    (day-to-close friday)
    (not (friday-load ?))
    =>
    (printout t "¿Cuál es la carga de cierres para el viernes?")
    (assert (friday-load ?load (read))))

(defrule determine-saturday-closing ""
    (day-to-close friday)
    (not(< friday-load 1000000))
    =>
    (assert (day-to-close saturday)))

(defrule day-to-close-conclulssion ""
    (day-to-close ?)
    =>
    (if (eq day-to-close MtTh) 
        then (printout t "Se puede cerrar de Lunes a Jueves")
        else (
            if (eq day-to-close friday) 
                then (printout t "Se debe cerrar viernes.") 
                else (printout t "Se debe cerrar sabado.")
             )
    ))
```

The errores are:

[ARGACCES5] Function < expected argument #1 to be of type integer or float

[PRCCODE3] Undefined variable size referenced in RHS of defrule.

[CSTRCPSR1] WARNING: Redefining defrule: determine-saturday-closing +j+j+j

[CSTRCPSR1] WARNING: Redefining defrule: day-to-close-conclulssion +j+j

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some suggest revisions:

```
(defrule determine-closing-date
    (not (day-to-close ?))
    (billing-size ?billing-size)
    (unpaid-invoices-number ?unpaid-invoices-number)
    =>
    (if (or (< ?billing-size 1000000)
            (< ?unpaid-invoices-number 1000000))
        then (assert (day-to-close MtTh))
        else (assert (day-to-close friday))))

(defrule determine-billing-size ""
    (not (billing-size ?))
    (not (day-to-close ?))
    =>
    ; What is the size of the billing?
    (printout t "¿Cuál es el tamaño de la facturacion? ")
    (bind ?size (read))
    (assert (billing-size ?size)))

(defrule determine-unpaid-invoices-number ""
    (not (unpaid-invoices-number ?))
    (not (day-to-close ?))
    =>
    ; What is the amount of unpaid bills?
    (printout t "¿Cuál es la cantidad de facturas no pagadas? ")
    (bind ?size (read))
    (assert (unpaid-invoices-number ?size)))

(defrule determine-friday-load ""
    (day-to-close friday)
    (not (friday-load ?))
    =>
    ; What is the burden of closures for Friday?
    (printout t "¿Cuál es la carga de cierres para el viernes? ")
    (bind ?load (read))
    (assert (friday-load ?load)))

(defrule determine-saturday-closing ""
    ?dtc <- (day-to-close friday)
    (friday-load ?load&:(< ?load 1000000))
    =>
    (retract ?dtc)
    (assert (day-to-close saturday)))

(defrule day-to-close-conclusion ""
    (declare (salience -10))
    (day-to-close ?day-to-close)
    =>
    (switch ?day-to-close
       (case MtTh 
             ; Can be closed from Monday to Thursday.
             then (printout t "Se puede cerrar de Lunes a Jueves." crlf))
       (case friday 
             ; Must be closed Fridays.
             then (printout t "Se debe cerrar viernes." crlf))
       (default 
             ; Must be closed Saturday.
             then (printout t "Se debe cerrar sabado." crlf))))
```

And the output it produces:

```
CLIPS> Loading Buffer...
******
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
¿Cuál es el tamaño de la facturacion? 10
¿Cuál es la cantidad de facturas no pagadas? 10
Se puede cerrar de Lunes a Jueves.
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
¿Cuál es el tamaño de la facturacion? 3000000
¿Cuál es la cantidad de facturas no pagadas? 3000000
¿Cuál es la carga de cierres para el viernes? 10
Se debe cerrar sabado.
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
¿Cuál es el tamaño de la facturacion? 3000000
¿Cuál es la cantidad de facturas no pagadas? 3000000
¿Cuál es la carga de cierres para el viernes? 3000000
Se debe cerrar viernes.
CLIPS>
```

Comment: Thankyou for your help! Can you tellme what I was doing wrong. I really want to learn this CLIPS languague

Comment: 1) The syntax used for binding variables was incorrect.

Comment: 2) In the determine-saturday-closing rule, the friday-load pattern needed to check for the existence of a load less than 1000000 rather than the non-existence of a fact with a load less than 1000000.
3) The day-to-close-conclusion rule needed to have a lower salience than the other rules so that it would execute only after all the other rules had been applied. If you remove the salience and run the program with billing size and paid bills of 3000000, you'll see why.

Comment: Thank you again. I run the program and worked like a charm. Just one other thing. If the billing-size is < than 1000000 I need to infer that the closing can be MtTh because the unpaid number can not be greater than the billing size.

Comment: I change the `determine-unpaid-invoices-number` to ask `(and (not (day-to-close ?))
         (not (unpaid-invoices-number ?))
    )` but is not working. Maybe something related to the salience may help.

Comment: Wrapping an "and" around that group of patterns shouldn't change its behaviour. "Not working" is pretty vague.

Comment: When I said "not working" I mean that, even when the Billing Size is < 1000000 the program ask me the Unpaid Number, but I want that when the billing sizes is not greater or equal than 1000000, automatically it infer that you can close it Monday to thursday